# How to use variables from another class file

Tags: c#

This is code inside Proizvod.cs file

```
namespace mateo_zadatak
{
    class Proizvod
    {

        public string Šifra = "šifra";
        public string Naziv = "naziv";
        public string Proizvođač = "proizvođač";
        public float Cijena;
        public int Količina;
        private float Ukupno;
        private int Popust;
        private float UkupnoPopust;


        private void variable()
        { 
           Ukupno = Cijena * Količina;
           {
              if (Količina < 10)
              {
                 Popust = 0;
              }
              else if (Količina > 9 && Količina < 31) 
              {
                 Popust = 5;
              }
              else Popust = 10;
           }

        }
    }
}
```

I have to use this variables in Form1.cs file , because i will need some calculations from datagrid. How to connect those two files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no `"Global"` variables in `C#` but what you can do is create a new `Class` with `Static` variables and `assign/use` them.  For example:

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static int IntVariable;
    public static string StringVariable;
}
```

And then you can reference them as `GlobalVariables.IntVariable` and `GlobalVariables.StringVariable`.

Answer (score 0):

A Form is just a class - Add public properties/members to the Form and access them from a reference to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class `public`, and make sure you include `Proizvod.cs` file into your project or add a reference to it from your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use public properties instead of variables from another class

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but:

```
public class Form1 : ...
{
    public Proizvod Foo;

    Form1()
    {
        Foo = new Proizvod();
    }

    SomeMethod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Foo.Naziv);
    }
}
```